# No se realiza la relacion ManytoMany

Tags: python, django, django-models, djangorestframework

Tengo los siguientes **modelos**:

```
class Persona(models.Model):
    cedula = models.CharField(max_length=12, unique=True, null=False, blank=False)
    rol = models.ManyToManyField('Rol')
    cuenta = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, primary_key=True, blank=True)

class Evaluador(Persona):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=60, unique=True, null=False, blank=True)

class Usuario(Evaluador):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    apellido = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    cargo = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Rol(models.Model):
    nom_rol = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    evalua = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

y esta es mi **vista**:

```
class UsuarioCreate(CreateView):
    model = Usuario
    template_name = 'pages/usuario_form.html'
    form_class = UsuarioForm
    second_form_class = UserCreationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('Principal:usuarios_lista')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(UsuarioCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if 'form' not in context:
            context['form'] = self.form_class(self.request.GET)
        if 'form2' not in context:
            context['form2'] = self.second_form_class(self.request.GET)
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        form2 = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
            usuario = form.save(commit=False)
            usuario.cuenta = form2.save()
            usuario.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
        else:
            return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form, form2=form2))
```

así se ve en la plantilla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que después de haber rellenado todos los campos, la relación de `Persona` con `cuenta` se realiza exitosamente, pero la relación con `rol` no se realiza.

En consola no me lanza ningún error y al revisar la base de datos la tabla intermedia de rol-persona esta vacía. Esto lo estoy haciendo desde un html no desde el admin de django.

Comment: No conozco mucho de django, pero piensa un poco: creas una `Persona` que puede crear uno o varios `Roles` que, a su vez, cada rol puede crear una o varias `Personas`,...y así cíclicamente. No es posible automatizar este proceso. Tendrás que usar un [`RelatedManager`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/relations/#related-objects-reference).

Answer (score 1):

La solución al problema despues de tanto rebuscar se logro añadiendo en la vista un

> form.save_m2m()

despues

> usuario.save()

Se tiene que añadir cuando se utiliza un `commit=False` ya que esto no guarda la asociación `ManyToMany`